# Set object value to type

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to set the type of a variable value, but not the variable it self.

```
type FontWeight = 'normal' | 'bold' | '100' | '200' | '300' | '400' | '500' | '600' | '700' | '800' | '900';
type StyleSheetStyle = {};

type FontStyleSheetStyle = { [key:FontWeight]:StyleSheetStyle };

const proximaNova = StyleSheet.create({
    // '100': { fontFamily:'' },
    // '200': { fontFamily:'' },
    '300': { fontFamily:'ProximaNova-Light' },
    '400': { fontFamily:'ProximaNova-Regular' },
    // '500': { fontFamily:'' },
    '600': { fontFamily:'ProximaNova-Semibold' },
    '700': { fontFamily:'ProximaNova-Bold' },
    // '800': { fontFamily:'' },
    // '900': { fontFamily:'' }
}: FontStyleSheetStyle);
```

On flow.org/try this warns:

> ```
> 18: }: FontStyleSheetStyle);
>      ^ Unexpected token :
> ```

I don't want to do:

```
let proixmaNova: FontStyleSheetStyle = { 100: {} }
proximaNova = StyleSheet.create(proximaNova);
```

I also had a side question. With my above code, I think FontStyleSheetStyle is a sealed object? How can make it required any of FontWeight as key, and any other properties? So a "unsealed object with some required keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add additional braces around the object within the create function call. This way you are casting the object to the desired `FontStyleSheetStyle` type. But if the rest is correctly typed, you shouldn't need the type definition at all. So either add the additional braces or remove the type completely.

Comment: Thanks Jan! I think that works. Do you know about the seoncd part, how to make a "unsealed object with some required keys"?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the 2nd part of your question, you can only have a single index per type definition. To accomplish what you're asking, you'd have to type out the "sealed" types by hand:

```
type SealedWithMap = {
  [key: string]: string,
  normal: StyleSheetStyle,
  bold: StyleSheetStyle,
  100: StyleSheetStyle,
  // ... etc ...
};
```